# Shouldn't Farquaad have been a Prince Regent in Fiona's Prologue?

Tags: shrek

There is an alternate opening to *Shrek* called Fiona's Prologue. In this opening, Fiona was born to the King and Queen of Duloc, who locked her in the tower because she was born an ogre. When they died, they left Duloc in Farquaad's hands.

Because Farquaad was called an "ambitious regent" and Duloc in this opening, shouldn't Farquaad have been a Prince Regent instead of a Lord?

Answer (score 3):

The title of Prince is usually gained either through heredity or by marriage (And may or may not have accession to the throne).

Regent is an appointed position, and lasts as long as the condition requiring a regent does. (i.e. the heir grows up, comes out of their coma, stops being an ogre, what have you). While they have the power of the throne, they don't actually belong on the throne.

So his proper title probably should be Lord Farquaad, Regent of Duloc

Comment: A prince-regent is a prince who's acting as the regent (e.g. usually because their parent, the king or queen is incapacitated).

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, but the regent doesn't require it to be a prince. The title is Prince-regent only when the Regent actually is a prince.